# On Click Scroll To List Item So It Shows On Top

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, listview

The functionality I'm trying to achieve is that when I click on a list item, it is automatically scrolled to so it shows on top. That's my code now:

```
groupRef?.current?.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth",
  block: "start",
});
```

But, it doesn't always work. A small scroll happens, but the item still not on top. My theory is that there is not enough space at the bottom for the scroll to fully accure (Because behind the scenes, a scroll bottom happens to the offset top of the list item element). How can I fix this?